# Good introduction to cohomology of spaces?

Tags: soft-question, homology-cohomology, online-resources

I'm trying to read chapter $3$ of Hatcher but I find it a bit difficult to read. I really only made it through the first two chapters because I had in-class lectures to go along with the reading. Does anybody know another resource that gives a good introduction to cohomology theory?

Comment: You could try Bredon's "Topology and Geometry", but I'm sad to say that Hatcher is easiest I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a super-summerized introduction you may want to check these course notes on singular homology :

http://math.arizona.edu/~rwilliams/SingularHomology.pdf

Again there is no proof or anything and it only covers the basic but I found it helpful just to, you know, see the big picture.

Hope that helps.